# Are all non-human creations reincarnations?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, soul, reincarnation, repentance-teshuvah

I have heard from my Rav and during a few derashot of HaRav Eliyahu Mansour that a neshamah previously brought into 'Olam HaZeh in human form, but needing additional *tiqqun* (i.e. soul correction) and no longer being able to achieve such tiqqun in human form (HaRav Mansour recently quoted an opinion that a neshamah can descend in human form a maximum of three times), can return to This World in other forms (i.e. animal, plant or inanimate form).

I'm no *mequbal* (i.e. Qabbalist); but, assuming my understanding above is correct, does that mean that every non-human creation is necessarily a *gilgul* (i.e. reincarnation) of a neshamah that was previously brought into This World in human form?

Comment: If "every non-human creation is necessarily a gilgul" then what did Adam and Eve see & eat? They were the firsts should to be here.

Comment: That was going to be my original question; but, I wanted to dial it back a step and clarify this point which might be a false assumption/understanding.

Comment: @DannySchoemann It's certainly conceivable a priori (though I have no idea whether it's actually true) that a reincarnation life can be *before* the life it's a reincarnation of.

Comment: That's like asking "I understand someone whose car has died needs to take public transport. Does that mean everyone on public transport has a non-working car?".

Comment: @msh210 Except that I know of many people who don't own cars and therefore use public transport. If someone is able to provide evidence for the same as regards my question, I would agree with you.

Comment: @msh210 - It's like asking "Have all cars been repaired in a body shop before being put on the road.". You are discussing PREcarnation - if there is even such a word. (Gilgul/reincarnation was defined as a soul needing tiqqun after blowing their first chance.)

Comment: I would like to know the source of three times. There are tsadikim who say they were originally one of Yaakov's sheep so it seems one can be an animal first! Will have to check.

Comment: http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21401&mobile=on  Found it. Very interesting about the yismach moshe!

Comment: @DannySchoemann My car analogy had nothing to do with my other comment. It was a comment on the question.

Comment: @DannySchoemann re "a soul needing tiqqun after blowing their first chance": But why can't that happen before the chance-blowing? It's all the same to God, isn't it? He knows the chance will be blown. And the incarnate person (and I assume animal etc.) doesn't know anyway.

Comment: According to this http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC33863/ the number of new prokaryotes (bacteria) every year is around 10^30. this number exceeds the total number of humans that ever lived.

Comment: All A are B, not all B are A

Comment: I've heard b'sheim R' Twersky that it's only true of dogs. Not sure what his source is, or why dogs specifically.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that some animals, plants ...  are gilgulim of people, that does not mean that all are. Reincarnation is usually because a soul has to fix something it did or did not do but for whatever reason can't go to gehinom or needs to be done in the physical world. Most souls however either throughout the course of their life completed what they needed and are able to be cleansed in gehinom of whatever impurities they may have picked up.
   Also to clarify there are 2 concepts  The return of a soul into a new body which happens quite often and the "piggybacking" of a soul into a body human or otherwise that already has a soul.(similar but not the same as a dibbuk). This is what you asked about(As well there is the resurrection of the dead by the times of mosiach).  In the case of the return of a soul, the soul I the person having full control over the actions of he person. Whereas by piggybacking the soul while it may provide some benefit to the body it inhabits (such as I think leaders get assistance from moshe rabeinu because a "piece" of his soul goes into their body) it does not have control over the person (unless of course it's a dibbuk) for sources see discussion about moshe rabeinu and yakov avinu an how Kabbalah explains the phrases moshe lo meis (Moshe did not die) and yakov lo meis. As well there is shar hagilgulim in eitz Chaim by R Chaim vital which should have everything.